# django: change the title of the model in the admin

Tags: django, django-admin

Django (1.4) by default adds the letter 's' to the model names in the admin site. For example, I have a model class nemed History. When looking in the admin site I found django named it History`s`.

How could I remove this letter and keep the model name as it is ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class ModelName(models.Model):
    .................

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = _("History")
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your own `verbose_name_plural` in model's Meta class.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#verbose-name-plural